# Wi-Fi drops after some time on Ubuntu 18.04 with Intel Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1]

Tags: wireless

I installed Ubuntu a few days ago. When I start the laptop I have Wi-Fi and I can use internet, but later the network disappears.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1]
(rev bb)

    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:4070]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Comment: You mean, you can't see the wifi network on Ubuntu ? Does it come back after sometime?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Please follow the instructions provided in the following post: https://askubuntu.com/a/425180/167115 Then, please edit your question and provide a link or post the information in your question. Thanks!

Comment: Done, now I have Wi-Fi because I reseted the laptop, but later I will lose the conexion...

Comment: Whenever possible, please post command outputs or other textual information as plain, (and if applicable) code formatted text. Pictures are badly accessible as we can not copy information, it resides on an external domain, etc. Thank you.

Comment: Okey, sorry. The Wi-Fi still failing, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you use GNOME or MATE, try `sudo service network-manager restart` in a terminal. That worked for me.